# Is there an algorithm for searching an element in skip-list with complexity O(log(k))

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, skip-lists

I got a pretty simple homework task at my University but still cannot solve it:
For a given value **X**, which's the first appearance in skip-list is an index **k**, create an algorithm that finds **X** in index **k** with Complexity **O(log(k))**. 
I saw previously that people asked about it but no question was answered clearly and understandably. I just cannot think about a way to do it. There is a very understandable solution for searching an element with a time **O(log(k))** in a simple array, where an exponential search is applied.
I will be very grateful if someone would describe an algorithm itself and the idea it uses.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: technically those question tend not to be answered on SO and are out scope. this is really just information **search** task :P

Answer (score 1):

First, go through the forwarding pointers in order to find the highest one you can traverse with out passing **X**.  That takes **O(log k)**.

Then, continue the search as usual, starting with that pointer instead of the highest one.  That also takes **O(log k)**.

Most data structures that offer **O(log N)** search also support an optimized search for nearby elements like this, at least when you're starting at either end.  It's called a "finger search": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_search

Comment: Isn't the search you describe the default skip list search algorithm?

Comment: Almost, but the default search algorithm starts with highest (farthest) pointer.

Comment: So your algorithm starts with the lowest pointer rather than the highest?

Comment: You walk up from the lowest pointer to find the highest one you can traverse, and then proceed normally from there.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Sorry, I did not understand. Even if your search space is now `k` once you have forwarded your first pointer, the complexity of searching in that space is still `O(log n)`, as for skip lists, the maximum height of the levels can be O(log n), right? You are not cutting down the levels, are you?

Answer (score -1):

According to http://bigocheatsheet.com/ search for skip list is O(log(n)).

Another useful resource aside from wiki(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/skip-list-set-3-searching-deletion/) pseudocode is:

```
Search(list, searchKey)
x := list -> header
-- loop invariant: x -> key  level downto 0 do
    while x -> forward[i] -> key  forward[i]
x := x -> forward[0]
if x -> key = searchKey then return x -> value
else return failure
```